# MySQL Variable Not Giving Expected Result

Tags: mysql

I have the MySQL query below which is assigning the results of a custom table into variables which I am using in my WHERE clause.

```
SET @Customer_Group = (SELECT CustomerGroup FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @Department = (SELECT Department FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @Due_Date = (SELECT DueDate FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @PriorDate = (SELECT PriorDate FROM car_promisquestions);

SET @QDate = IF( @PriorDate = 'Y', CONCAT('saw_order.`Date` > ', '(@Due_Date - INTERVAL 5 DAY)'), CONCAT("saw_order.`Date` = ", @Due_Date));

SELECT
saw_order.Wo,
saw_orderitem.Item,
saw_order.Date,
saw_orderitem.Qty,
saw_orderitem.ModelDescription,
saw_orderitem.ColorDescription,
saw_order.`Status`,
saw_orderitem.Product,
saw_orderitemdep.Employee,
saw_orderitemdep.EmpLastName,
saw_orderitemdep.EmpFirstName,
saw_orderitemdep.Department,
saw_orderitem.ProductDescription,
saw_orderitemdep.DeptDescription,
saw_orderitem.GGroupDescription
FROM
saw_order
INNER JOIN saw_orderitem ON saw_order.Wo = saw_orderitem.Wo
INNER JOIN saw_orderitemdep ON saw_order.Wo = saw_orderitemdep.Wo
CROSS JOIN car_promisquestions ON car_promisquestions.Warehouse = saw_order.Warehouse
WHERE
saw_orderitemdep.Department IN (@Department) AND
@QDate
GROUP BY
saw_orderitemdep.Department ASC,
saw_order.Wo ASC,
saw_orderitem.Item ASC
ORDER BY
saw_orderitemdep.Department ASC,
saw_order.Wo ASC,
saw_orderitem.Item ASC,
saw_order.Date ASC
```

The problem I am having is that `@QDate` does not seem to be outputting the result I am expecting. If I run `SELECT @QDate` after I set `@QDate` I get the result `saw_order.`Date`> (@Due_Date - INTERVAL 5 DAY)` which if I copy and paste in place of the `@QDate` variable in my WHERE clause works perfectly. So what am I doing wrong? Why does the result string work but the variable does not?

Comment: MySQL's user variables can only hold one result..You should have gotten error(s) on these lines `SET @Customer_Group = (SELECT CustomerGroup FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @Department = (SELECT Department FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @Due_Date = (SELECT DueDate FROM car_promisquestions);
SET @PriorDate = (SELECT PriorDate FROM car_promisquestions);`  see demo http://rextester.com/XNOQI62245

Comment: Well technically `car_promisquestions` will only ever have 1 row of data. So `@Customer_Group`, `@Department`, `@Due_Date` and `@PriorDate` do not throw errors.